# Detect touch over TableView and still be able to scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, touchesbegan

I need to be able to detect immediate touch and get its position. (so didSelectRowAtIndexPath can't help us since it does not act immediately when scrolling up and down fast, you need to breathe in and select one by one)

Already tried everything I can think of. Touches began in each cell does not work because it suddenly behaves like didSelectRowIndexPath when implemented in custom cell class. Same result with TableViewController, the nature of touches began (you touch it, respond right away) just won't work.

*** I'm not trying to TAP. Need to be able to get TOUCH (TapGesture does not respond when swiping very carefully/slowly but touches began always does) ***

Comment: what functionality you are trying to achieve.   didSelectRowAtIndexPath is used to select the row.

Comment: Ok so, I've implemented a view on the left side of cells and it moves up and down depending on which cell the user taps on. I got it to work in my other project when I made my own fully customized TableView only with UIViews and nothing else. Because I did not have to work with cells or any of anything, just needed the position of tapped area and then simply moved the view up and down, done. Now working with actual UITableView.. Disoriented.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's what you need, but you can create a `TapGestureRecognizer`.

You will likely run into conflicts with the UITableView's own gesture recognisers, but there are mechanisms to solve these which should hopefully let you achieve your desired behaviour (look up `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` and `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`'s `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` and `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

In cellForIndexpath method.

```
      UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
            [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                    action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
            singleFingerTap.delegate=self;
            cell.contentView.tag=indexPath.row;
            [cell.contentView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];



//The event handling method
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)recognizer.view.tag);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do, add UILongPressGestureRecognizer to tableview, so normal touch will scroll and long press will do whatever you want to. Set its minimumPressDuration like 0.2 so it won't take much time. Add action for UILongPressGestureRecognizer and in that method get location like:

```
CGPoint touchPointInView = [sender locationInView: self.view]; //location reespective to view
CGPoint touchPointInView1 = [sender locationInView: tableView]; //location respective to tableview
```

Comment: what's the issue with it? because I am doing same thing with above code. I also want to scroll and doing something on long press and its working for me.

Comment: It kind of works but if you touch it really really really delicately, it doesn't respond. It does work perfectly with any other part of the screen that is not TableView but once I try it on TableView, it behaves differently.

Comment: any other part of screen? you added it to view? I asked to add UILongPressGestureRecognizer to tableview

Comment: Yes I did and it behaved just like I said and then I tried it on somewhere else just to see and that worked therefore it just behaves differently on TableView because I tried it on everywhere.